# NDB Query: reverse relationships of ndb.KeyProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

i've this model

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
    token = ndb.StringProperty(default="x")
    follows = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User", repeated=True)
    picture = ndb.StringProperty()
```

right now i know, for each user, what are the people he follows.
But, how can i know the people that follows me?
example:

```
A.follows=[B,..]
C.follows=[B,..]
B.getWhoFollowsMe = [A,C]
```

basically, how can i create the getWhoFollowsMe function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getWhoFollowsMe(me_key):
  return User.query().filter(User.follows==me_key)
```

Comment: mmm, i tried and returns: `Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received False`
Btw i put apicies around follows.
PS: the follows is an array, will it work with `==` operator?

Comment: `User.query().filter(User.follows == me_key).fetch(1000)` works

Answer (score 3):

You can use @Hernan's function, but you can also implement it as a property or ClassMethod for convenience.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
    token = ndb.StringProperty(default="x")
    follows = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User", repeated=True)
    picture = ndb.StringProperty()

    @property
    def followers(self):
        return User.query().filter(self.follows == self.key).fetch(1000)
```

Thus later access it like

```
user.followers
```

But yeah maybe my answer is excessive and I think @Hernan's should be the correct accepted one

Comment: this does not work. there's a problem with `follows` parameter (not a global name)

Comment: how can i have also the people that are not my followers?
i tried with `!=` but it misses all the people who have `follows` as empty

Comment: @EsseTi Excuse me but what do you need to achieve? First you get a list of followers. Then you want a list with all the users in you db except the ones the user follows? or just all? Got me confused here.

Comment: i need two functions, one with the followers, and one with the non followers. i tried with a query but it does not work. i can do it by doing all-follower anyway.

Comment: @EsseTi I don't think you can manage it with a query. What you need to do is 1-> Get the followers 2->Get all people and remove the followers. I ll check if there is a better way if I find some time. In the meanwhile maybe you want to open this problem as another question and then if still not getting any answer just mention me and I ll help

Comment: i see, i tried with a double != but it's not possibile. i'll use the double query approach for the meanwhile.
Thanks